# Loop VBA macro to open files in a folder, import row, then move to another folder using relative paths

Tags: vba, excel, import

I am attempting to make a loop VBA macro to:

1. Open first file in folder called `New`
2. Copy data row in `Defined Name` cell range `export_data`
3. Paste it into my current workbook on a new row at `A1` on `Sheet1`
4. Close without saving file from which data was imported and move it to `Archived` folder
5. Repeat until no files left in `New` folder.

My file structure is as follows:

[image: File Structure]

All files in the `New` folder are identical (except name) `.xlsm` files. Each has a `Defined Name` cell range called `export_data` with the single row of cells I need to import into my `Dashboard.xlsm`.

I would like the macro to use relative paths for the `New` and `Archived` folders as it would allow me to move the entire set of files anywhere and still work.

At present I have gotten as far as adapting as best I could the code [from this post](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/818972-macro-pull-all-data-every-file-folder-copy-data-into-open-workbook.html) trying to get the macro to move the files:

```
Option Explicit


Const FOLDER_PATH = "C:\Users\OneDrive\Projects\Audit Sheet\"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH

Sub ImportWorksheets()
   '=============================================
   'Process all Excel files in specified folder
   '=============================================
   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row

   rowTarget = 2

   'check the folder exists
   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'reset application settings in event of error
   On Error GoTo errHandler
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False



   'loop through the Excel files in the folder
   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""

      'open the source file and set the source worksheet - ASSUMED WORKSHEET(1)
      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
      'Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1) 'EDIT IF NECESSARY

      'import the data

      'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
      wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
      'rowTarget = rowTarget + 1

      sFile = Dir()
   Loop

errHandler:
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   'tidy up
   Set wsSource = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
End Sub




Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

Comment: You can perform two [Save As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173898/how-to-do-a-save-as-in-vba-code-saving-my-current-excel-workbook-with-datesta) calls (one for `archive` before making any changes and one for `new` after changes have been applied) and then [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835/deleting-a-file-in-vba) the file when you are done. Modify as needed to get your [relative file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213584/relative-instead-of-absolute-paths-in-excel-vba).

Comment: That is a good idea, but that would cause the file to save once more, I would rather avoid saving it again in case any of the data is altered. I may sound cautious but I'd like to avoid any potential data losses.

Comment: I hadn't considered this way of doing this thank you. I will try it, but how would you go about using relative folder paths rather than absolute?

Comment: Thank you that is much appreciated. I wish I were already at a level where this were practice over an exercise in frustration :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the `FileSystemObject` for path and file references and file move.  Use `ThisWorkbook.Path` as the base for your relative paths (based on the Dashboard workbook location as per the OP)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim fldBase As Folder
    Dim fldNew As Folder
    Dim fldArchived As Folder
    Dim fWb As File
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wsDashboard As Worksheet
    Dim OldCalc As XlCalculation

    Const NAMED_RANGE = "export_data"

    On Error GoTo EH:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    OldCalc = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Set reference to data destination sheet
    Set wsDashboard = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportData")  '<-- adjust to your ws name in Dashboard

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fldBase = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)

    'Check if \New and \Archive exist
    If Not fso.FolderExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New") Then Exit Sub
    If Not fso.FolderExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Archived") Then Exit Sub

    Set fldNew = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New")
    Set fldArchived = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Archived")

    For Each fWb In fldNew.Files
        If fWb.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
            ' Open File
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fWb.Path, ReadOnly:=True)
            Set nm = wb.Names(NAMED_RANGE)
            Set rng = nm.RefersToRange

            ' Copy Data
            With wsDashboard
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count) = rng.Value
            End With

            ' Close File
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

            ' Move File
            fso.MoveFile Source:=fWb.Path, Destination:=fldArchived.Path & "\" & fWb.Name

        End If

    Next
CleanUp:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = OldCalc
Exit Sub
EH:
    Stop ' <--- For debug purposes
    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

Don't forget to add a reference to the FileSystemObject, or convert to late binding [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092571/445425) -

Comment: That is amazing, I had given up on the FSO method without realising that it wasn't running due to my poor coding, but rather because I hadn't enabled `Microsoft Script Runtime` as explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba)

Comment: Again thank you for y our help! Am I missing something or does that link also describe the conversion to late binding you speak of?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Changed to a better link

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Learning so much from this. Have a great day!

Comment: @chrisneilsen any reason in particular for the `on error goto`? I seem to get mercilessly shamed when using that bit of code on here lol. Saving this solution, def better then my attempt

Comment: @urdearboy  on error goto error handler is quite normal for handling errors.  What often gets criticized is on error resume next without being tightly wrapped around a potential error and a corresponding on error goto 0 or EH.

Answer (score 1):

Your frustration became my frustration for a while, but alas, tested and working:

This will:

1. Cycle through each file as you specified
2. Save a unchanged copy in `RelativePath` > `Archived`
3. Add code to do what you want to do (here, Add Sheet)
4. Save the updated copy in `RelativePath` > `New`
5. Delete the original file

The `SaveAs` file paths are relative as you asked. However, if you move the folder which contains your original excels, you will have to update the variable `RelativePath`, nothing else will need to be modified though. To make this completely dynamic, you will need to find a way to dynamically assign the path to `RelativePath` (File Dialogue instead?)

This will error out if there is no folder "Archived" or "New" in the same directory as the workbooks you are opening.

```
Option Explicit
Const RelativePath = "C:\urdearboy\Desktop\Test\"
```

```
Sub ImportWorksheets()
Dim sFile As String
Dim wbSource As Workbook

Dim wbArchive As String, wbNew As String, KillFile As String

If Not FileFolderExists(RelativePath) Then
    MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

sFile = Dir(RelativePath & "*.xls*")
Do Until sFile = ""

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(RelativePath & sFile)
KillFile = wbSource.Path & "\" & wbSource.Name

    'Save Archive
    wbArchive = RelativePath & "Archived\" & wbSource.Name
    wbSource.SaveAs Filename:=wbArchive

        'Do your thing here (I'm just adding a sheet to test code)
        wbSource.Sheets.Add

    'Save new file with changes that are made above
    wbNew = RelativePath & "New\" & wbSource.Name
    wbSource.SaveAs Filename:=wbNew

'Delete Sourcebook
wbSource.Close False
Kill KillFile

sFile = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wbSource = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

Disclaimer: This is my first attempt at anything like this. I cannot speak to the efficiency of this in comparison to what a more experienced coder may be able to provide.

Comment: I will go and test it, I think I saw somewhere that there is a way to find the current path to the current workbook and that could be a way to dynamically set the Relative Path. I will investigate further, but this is already a massive step forwards, thank you for your time and effort thus far.

Comment: But if my limited understanding of coding affords me a 2-cent, isn't that the `wbSource.Path` for the opened file for the data to be exported from? Couldn't that be called at the beginning of the macro to set the `RelativePath` variable from the `Dashboard` workbook? Using `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba)